# Opening another app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, url

When you open another app from your app with URL. Is there possible to put a back button in that app to get back to your app?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope not.  That app belongs to someone else.

Comment: No, it isn't possible. (Imagine what you could do otherwise...)

Comment: It's the user's choice to return to the previous app. This is easily done by double-tapping the Home button and selecting the other app from the recently-used-apps list.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible for two mutually cooperating apps:

App A opens `appBschema://whatever?back=appAschema%3a%2f%2fdontcare`
and to implement the 'back' button app B can open `appAschema://dontcare`

Answer (score 1):

In any normal scenario, no, it's someone else's app and you can't do anything to it.

If the other app is yours however, and you expect to swap between them, you could do that in the other application, but in that application and not the one you are trying to open back.